# Autostart service on boot in Docker-Container

Tags: docker, debian, apache2, boot, systemctl

I have a strange problem:

I created a docker-container (debian image) and installed an apache-server. However when i restart the container, everything else is there but the server is not starting on bootup. I added apache2 with the systemctl command, but still it is not working. I don't know if this is a docker thing or a debian problem.

Greets

Comment: Can you provide your Dockerfile and/or run commands?

Answer (score 4):

On docker image you have not to deal with systemd to start a program. Instead take a look at the Dockerfile's directives ENTRYPOINT and CMD (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint and https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd).

If you want to have an apache inside a container there are some images available on docker hub. You can look to the Dockerfile to have an idea on how it works.

Comment: Forgot to mention that i am running docker on a synology :( i do not know how to deal with dockerfiles there ..